# Save parts of a website as pure text

Tags: website, screen-scraping

I hope I may ask this here.

I need to extract the contents of an existing website (in charge of the website owner) to Word (or text) documents. For this, I only need the content from one DIV with a given ID.

Is there any tool for Windows that can do this for me (ideally recursively)? I know wget and Web Site Downloader, but both can "only" save the complete HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to build your own toolchain for this:

1. Use a tool such as `wget` to recursively download the HTML files from which content is needed.  Pay special attention to options `-r` to specify recursive downloading, and `-l` to specify depth of the recursion.  `wget` outputs plain text.
2. Use a tool such as `grep` to filter out everything except the line(s) containing the `<DIV>` you need.  Pay special attention to options `-r` to specify recursive searching, and `-e` to specify a regular expression.  Pipe `grep`'s output to a file of your choice.  `grep` outputs plain text if it is fed plain text.

**Hint:** It may be simpler to use `grep` multiple times to filter out things in smaller chunks.  This depends entirely on how similar all of the various pages are, and how clean the code is.

---

**Edit:** Then again, perhaps [using a regex is *not* a good way to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: **Another Hint:** You may want to consider **sed** if **grep** doesn't do all of what you need.  Not all web sites conveniently place carriage returns to put each DIV on a line by itself.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think something like this already exists. I think your best option would be to code something up yourself.

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a... beautiful Python library that will let you do this in very minimal code. For more help, I suggest you head over to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup)

Comment: Well, if I code it myself, I would look there, sure. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm lazy.  In the time it would take you to research and set up a special-purpose tool, surely you can just highlight the required text with a mouse, copy it, and paste it into a text editor?

Comment: This is what I'm doing already. But it is boring and error-prone. That's why I'm searching for a tool to help me.